# The Graph nodes can't decode ABI encoded data containing arrays

Tags: abi, abiencoderv2, graphs

I'm currently having an issue with decoding a function call inside a Subgraph mapping that seems to be related to builtin abi decoder of a Graph node:

Given this input:

```
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
```

This **doesn't** work (mapping.ts of subgraph), it returns `null`, no error message given.

```
const decoded = ethereum.decode(
    '(address[],uint256[],uint32,bytes32[],bytes)',
    input
  );
```

whereas this works ([Rust cli](https://github.com/rust-ethereum/ethabi), 13.0 & latest):

```
ethabi decode params -t address[] -t uint256[] -t uint32 -t bytes32[] -t bytes <input>
```

outputs:

```
address[] [f36e7bc1dae85ed18cd492f9e856acf2bd13398e]
uint256[] [1]
uint32 1
bytes32[] []
bytes
```

(and it also works using the [abidecoder from ethers.js](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/coder/#AbiCoder-decode) ->

```
ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.decode(["address[]", "uint256[]", "uint32", "bytes32[]", "bytes"], inp)
```

Sidenote: **this** actually works inside a mapping, so I assume the issue might be related to arrays (or their abi notation) :

```
const decoded = ethereum.decode('(address,uint256,uint32)', input);
```

what am I missing?

Comment: I dug through the origin sources but can't find any hint why this should fail:

https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node/blob/master/runtime/wasm/src/host_exports.rs#L650
https://github.com/graphprotocol/ethabi/blob/master/ethabi/src/decoder.rs#L41

also works on command line build of the graph fork

Answer (score 3):

They can, actually. I ran into a totally different problem: decoding **tuples** vs. decoding **arrays**.

When trying to call `ethereum.decode` using this type string `(address[],uint256[],uint32,bytes32[],bytes)` it actually tries to decode a **tuple** of those types (denoted by the outer braces). There is no way I found to tell the [EthABI based decoder](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node/blob/master/runtime/wasm/src/host_exports.rs#L650) to use a type/param-string like `address[],uint256[],uint32,bytes32[],bytes`, so I dug into how Ethereum's ABI Encoder encodes tuples.

Given the input from above, if you prepend it with

`0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020`

it's recognized as a tuple of the parameter list by the decoder and can be decoded.

Here's some code that proves that behaviour:

```rs
use ethabi::decode;
use ethabi::param_type::{ParamType, Reader};
use hex_literal::hex;

//this code is here to demonstrate function parameter decoding with a prefixed tuple code
fn main() {
    let types: &str = "(address[],uint[],uint,bytes32[],bytes)";
    let param_types_str = Reader::read(&types).unwrap(); //or_else(|e| Err(anyhow::anyhow!("Failed to read types: {}", e)));
    let param_types_def = ParamType::Tuple(vec![
        Box::new(ParamType::Array(Box::new(ParamType::Address))),
        Box::new(ParamType::Array(Box::new(ParamType::Uint(256)))),
        Box::new(ParamType::Uint(256)),
        Box::new(ParamType::Array(Box::new(ParamType::FixedBytes(32)))),
        Box::new(ParamType::Bytes),
    ]);

    println!("type(str): {:?}", param_types_str);
    println!("type(def): {:?}", param_types_def);

    let encoded = hex!(
        "

        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 
        
        00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0
        00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000120
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
        000000000000000000000000f36e7bc1dae85ed18cd492f9e856acf2bd13398e
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        "
    );

    let res_str = decode(&[param_types_str], &encoded).unwrap();
    println!("decoded(str): {:?}", res_str);

    let res_def = decode(&[param_types_def], &encoded).unwrap();
    println!("decoded(def): {:?}", res_def);
}
```

```sh
type(str): Tuple([Array(Address), Array(Uint(256)), Uint(256), Array(FixedBytes(32)), Bytes])
type(def): Tuple([Array(Address), Array(Uint(256)), Uint(256), Array(FixedBytes(32)), Bytes])
decoded(str): [Tuple([Array([Address(0xf36e7bc1dae85ed18cd492f9e856acf2bd13398e)]), Array([Uint(1)]), Uint(1), Array([]), Bytes([])])]
decoded(def): [Tuple([Array([Address(0xf36e7bc1dae85ed18cd492f9e856acf2bd13398e)]), Array([Uint(1)]), Uint(1), Array([]), Bytes([])])]
```

In terms of The Graph you can actually "convert" an input argument of a function parameter list that you want to decode, by prefixing it with that encoded tuple bytes. In AssemblyScript it looks like:

```ts
import {  
  Bytes,
  ByteArray,
  ethereum
} from '@graphprotocol/graph-ts';

const functionInput = event.transaction.input.subarray(4);

//prepend a "tuple" prefix (function params are arrays, not tuples)
const tuplePrefix = ByteArray.fromHexString(
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020'
);

const functionInputAsTuple = new Uint8Array(
  tuplePrefix.length + functionInput.length
);

//concat prefix & original input
functionInputAsTuple.set(tuplePrefix, 0);
functionInputAsTuple.set(functionInput, tuplePrefix.length);

const tupleInputBytes = Bytes.fromUint8Array(functionInputAsTuple);
const decoded = ethereum.decode(
  '(address[],uint[],uint,bytes32[],bytes)',
  tupleInputBytes
);

const t = decoded.toTuple();
const originAddresses = t[0].toAddressArray();
const firstAddress = originAddresses[0];
```

Comment: Wow, incredible work thank you