# Cannot decode function call in subgraph code

Tags: the-graph, subgraph

This is with:

- graph-cli v0.34.0
- graph-ts v0.28.0

I'm trying to decode a function call in my subgraph mapping but it's not working. There is a tuple in the function input that seems to be causing the problem.

So I tried to debug at the command line making sure to prepend for tuples (taken from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114582/the-graph-nodes-cant-decode-abi-encoded-data-containing-arrays)). So I tried to debug at the command line using ethabi (example transaction [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x27d0b4b16aeb8accbccb8035af3412e8559638c1f20e796880dfabbe22a0eae5)) with the following:

```
ethabi decode params -t (address,uint256,uint256,address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint8,uint256,uint256,bytes32,uint256,bytes32,bytes32,uint256,(uint256,address)[],bytes) 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
```

This produces

```
no matches found: (address,uint256,uint256,address,address,address,uint256,uint256,uint8,uint256,uint256,bytes32,uint256,bytes32,bytes32,uint256,(uint256,address)[],bytes)
```

So I tried breaking the typestring down to individual parameters like this:

```
ethabi decode params -t address -t uint256 -t uint256 -t address -t address -t address -t uint256 -t uint256 -t uint8 -t uint256 -t uint256 -t bytes32 -t uint256 -t bytes32 -t bytes32 -t uint256 -t (uint256,address)[] -t bytes 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
```

This was a bit more promising as it tells me `no matches found: (uint256,address)[]` so that tuple is causing my problems. Is it possible to create a type string for `ethereum.decode` that contains tuples? If not is there a work around to so I can map this function call? I know I can map calls directly but that's not recommended as it is VERY slow to index.